# Detect "Enter" key and paint the textarea component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Before explaining the issue, I will explain my requirement and why I chose to create this custom component.

I have a requirement where whenever the user enters something in textarea, the textarea's height should increase/decrease automatically based on the entered text.

Since, textarea adds a scrollbar when content is increased but not stretch automatically. I thought to use contenteditable div instead of textarea. But contenteditable div has a problem in mobiles that we can't tap on the entered text.

So, I created a custom component where whatever I add in textarea, the same content will be added in a hidden div. and later the textarea will take out the height of the hidden div. This is working fine.

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqfkqc8y/3/)

But I have a small problem that whenever the user is pressing "enter", this component is unable to adjust the textarea's height. and later if I press any letter, the textarea is adjusting properly. The problem is with just detecting "Enter" key that pressed at the end of the content (*if the user pressed "Enter" key in mid of the content, this component is working fine*).

Here is the component's HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="textarea-clone"></div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: use oninput/onkeyup instead of onkeydown/onkeypress

Comment: or even better you can user change event!

Comment: "*Since, textarea adds a scrollbar when content is increased but not stretch automatically*" Check this: http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

Comment: @Mi-Creativity I can do the same in small code as you can see in my fiddle. I don't require a plugin here.

Comment: @dandavis I am using `keyup`.. check my fiddle.

Comment: you're using a `div` that example uses `textarea`

Comment: why not simply set rows on the textarea instead of fussing with hidden text? http://jsfiddle.net/aqfkqc8y/5/

Comment: @dandavis good one but not only `\n` is responsible for new row. The new row could also be added when content is overflown. (_Check your fiddle by writing just letters but not 'enter' key_)

Comment: @Mi-Creativity I think you haven't checked my fiddle. I am also using textarea. The div which I am using is hidden and is used only to get dimensions.

Comment: I've checked it and seen how it works even with a little glitch, in that link he is using textarea only

Comment: @Mi-Creativity I am also using Textarea and a three lines of JS code. to solve a small glitch why would I use a plugin? That is clearly overkill..

Comment: you can do it with out a plugin, i was showing you that you can add rows to the `textarea` while in your question you said "since textarea adds.."

Comment: As well as what @dandavis posted, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/fusdhw2x/ which adds rows while typing if you reach the end of the last row,, no plugin and no DIV!!

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Your fiddle breaks on many cases. please check by pressing "enter".

Comment: @Mr_Green, I didn't say my code will work for the enter key that what dandavis already did hence why i said "*as well as*, i already did the enter thing with `if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)` but the solution dandavis posted was better because it works for adding and removing newlines.. in my code you can change the `input` event with `keydown` and it will better, after all these are examples this why we posting them as comments not as answers. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ...

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', function (e) {
    if(code == 13) {  // keycode == 13 (enter)
        $('.textarea-clone').text($(this).val());
    }
});
```

EDIT:

This works for me and only resizes on enter key presses, thinking about it that's likely not your intention but this tests that specific scenario.

Maybe this is a browser thing, some browsers don't correctly implement all the events right, maybe try attaching to change, keypress, and keydown too, experiment and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

expanding on my comment to include overflow lines:

```
<textarea id=ta></textarea>

ta.oninput=function(){
    this.rows=this.value.split("\n").length; 
    while(this.clientHeight < this.scrollHeight-2) this.rows=this.rows+1;
};
```

this is a good setup because it adjusts to pastes, long text, enter keys, and whatever else makes it need to be taller.

i think you might need to adjust the border+padding allotment.
2px is default on fiddle (0px padding + 1px each border) and works perfect.

obligatory fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aqfkqc8y/6/